# this.props.value is undefined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't understand why I get undefined from this.props.loggedIn when passed to the child component.

parent component:

```
class App extends Component {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            loggedIn:true
        }
        this.logUser = this.logUser.bind(this);
    }


    logUser(){
        alert("logUser");
    }
    
    
    render() {
        const loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;
        return (
                <Container fluid className="container" >
                        <Nav loggedIn={loggedIn}/>
                        <Router>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                                <Route path="/user" component={Registration} />
                                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                            </Switch>
                        </Router>
                        {/* <Registration /> */}
                        {/* <Home/> */}
                        <Footer />
                </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

child component:

```
class navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("this.props")
        console.log(this.props.loggedIn) //I get undefined here!`enter code here`
       
        this.prova = this.prova.bind(this);
    }
```

I tried it all... still can't figure out why it happens.

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is!

Comment: Is `Nav` alias import of `navbar`?

Comment: @namgold thank you my friend, the problem was really stupid. I messed up with my imports. thank you very much

Comment: You could close your question instead add `[SOLVED]` into the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use Navbar instead of navbar. All components must have capital names. if it's not, it would be treated as dom element

Comment: Thanks! that was not the problem but the advice is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change your `navbar` component to look like this

```
class Nav extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // props is already defined so you don't need to use this
        console.log(props.loggedIn);
    }
}
```

Also in your `App` component change

```
const loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;
```

to

```
const { loggedIn, ...state } = this.state;
```